# Copy the 'explicit' or 'E' symbol from songs in the iOS Music app

Tags: ios, music, font, music.app

I have songs in my Music app that are marked as 'explicit'.

Is there a way to copy this 'explicit'/'E' symbol so I can use it somewhere else?

[image: explicit]
[image: explicit second]

Comment: If only I can show you a photo, okay so you k ow when you are listening to a song right? And the song is explicit, has curse words. So itunes adds an explicit tag next to the song title.

Comment: I need a way to copy and paste the "E" next to the title.

Comment: @CousinCocaine I need it in text every time I try to add it into the song title for my other music app it just says "explicit small"

Comment: It is not text. It is a PNG.

Comment: Do you see the other picture @CousinCocaine

Comment: ? I put it up here. Yes I have seen it. You start to get a bit annoying. The 'E' symbol looks like text, but it is an image.

Answer (score 6):

He is probably looking for the following unicode character : [️Negative Squared Latin Capital Letter E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f174/index.htm)

The letter :

NB: The letter is not visible on my Windows. My iPhone displays it.

Comment: Yes! Of course! But how am I able to copy it in text?

Comment: You can't copy it from the app. But you can do it from here :)

Comment: Sorry but from where?

Comment: I am on a phone

Comment: You can also get it from Character Table on your Mac. Press `⌘`+`⌃`+`Space` and search for "Negative Squared" -> You'll get more squared symbols there.

Comment: I'm on my iPhone I'm sorry if I did not mention it before

Comment: On my phone it's just a square

Comment: Can I have it in a square?

Comment: There's another one related to that one that it without rounded edges

Comment: Which iOS version ?

Comment: 8.2 Is what I am on

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/segoe_ui_emoji/index.htm This is the one I mean

Comment: Have you found out how I am able to copy it on iOS 8.2

Comment: Are you there? I don't know I've been trying to look this whole time.

Comment: There is no character white rounded edges. Like said above, the one with rounded edges is an image.

Answer (score 5):

## The 'E' is not text, it is artwork.

iTunes on your Mac has the same artwork. This artwork is located within the iTunes app. This is how you can find it:

- Go to /Applications
- Right click 'iTunes' and select 'Show Package Contents'
- Now go to 'Contents' -> 'Resources' -> 'English' (or any other installed language)
- In here you will find the artwork in png format. The 'ViewLineItemRatingE' is the one you are looking for. The @2x suffix means that it is double the resolution and is meant for retina displays.

[image: explicit small]

[image: explicit large]

*Note: I do not know about copy rights on this artwork. This might differ between countries as well.*

Comment: I really need it in text

Comment: it doesn't exist 'in text' it's a picture.

Comment: It's an image, there is *no* text.

Comment: It is not text, it is an image.

Comment: jynx, jynx, jynx. can't argue with right though. Moving forward, If you can't find something similar in the comprehensive http://unicode-table.com I'll eat my 

Comment: Yep, still couldent find it @ProductionValues